# How to print the "alt" key for the image uploaded along with src in the text-angular plugin using angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

Hi i need to send the alt key for the image when an image is uploaded using the text-angular plugin

I have tried the code but for me the alt key is not coming

STEP 1 :

HTML page

```
<text-angular  placeholder="hello world">
</text-angular>
```

STEP 2:

OUTPUT

```
When an image is uploaded its taking only the src, I need to add ALT key also

Please refer the images below
```

[image: Please refer the image for the better view]

Comment: I think you need to customize the plugin yourself by looking at the code

Comment: Hi aditya i have tried , but nothing worked

Comment: We can try to help if you provide the error/roadblock you are facing when you tried to update the original plugin.